# Run all functions or 'rollback'

Tags: powershell, error-handling

I have a PowerShell function that calls other functions to do a number of actions and I either want all of them to succeed or all of them to 'rollback' like a SQL transaction. A contrived example is below.

```
function MyFunction {
    Write-MessageToDatabase -Message 'Process Starting'
    Move-FolderX -Source '\\server1\share1\folder1' -Destination '\\server2\share2\folder2'
    Delete-FolderY -Path '\\server1\share1\folder1'
    Create-FileInFolderZ -Content 'Hello World'
    Write-MessageToDatabase -Message 'Process Stopping'
}
```

Is there any way that this can be done in PowerShell? I have looked at transactions (Start-Transaction), but it says that the provider has to support transactions and the paths are network paths.

Comment: Unfortunately, the `Registry` provider is the only built-in provider that provides transaction support. My suggestion would be to move any non-recoverable steps (eg. `Delete-FolderY`) to as late as possible to ensure you've processed anything else that might go wrong first

Answer (score 0):

As @MathiasR.Jessen states, SharePoint doesn't support transactions for much anything. You could check if all the commands are possible to run using the `-WhatIf` option and then go ahead if all what-if are successful.
That is, if all functions used supports `-WhatIf`.

```
function Invoke-MyFunction {
  try {
    # First do a whatif
    Write-MessageToDatabase -Message 'Process Starting' -WhatIf
    Move-FolderX `
      -Source '\\server1\share1\folder1' `
      -Destination '\\server2\share2\folder2' `
      -WhatIf
    Delete-FolderY -Path '\\server1\share1\folder1' -WhatIf
    Create-FileInFolderZ -Content 'Hello World' -WhatIf
    Write-MessageToDatabase -Message 'Process Stopping' -WhatIf

    # Then hope this was enough and send it 
    Write-MessageToDatabase -Message 'Process Starting'
    Move-FolderX `
      -Source '\\server1\share1\folder1' `
      -Destination '\\server2\share2\folder2'
    Delete-FolderY -Path '\\server1\share1\folder1'
    Create-FileInFolderZ -Content 'Hello World'
    Write-MessageToDatabase -Message 'Process Stopping'
  }
  catch {
    Write-Error 'Some actions couldn't be performed'
  }
}
```

This will still not guarantee that all commands will run successfully.

In that case you will have to provide a set of counter commands for each step and make sure the corresponding reverting steps are called in each catch phase...

```
function Invoke-MyFunction {
<#
.NOTES
  Steps tried by this function are

  1. Write start-message
  2. Move a folder
  3. Delete a folder
  4. Create a file
  5. Write complete-message

#>

  try {#1
    Write-StartMessage
  }
  catch {# no rollback
    Write-Error '#1 Fail'
    return
  }

  try {#2
    Move-Folder
  }
  catch {# rollback 1
    Write-Error '#2 Fail'

    Undo-StartMessage

    return
  }

  try {#3
    Create-File
  }
  catch {# rollback 2 & 1
    Write-Error '#3 Fail'

    Revert-FolderMove
    Undo-StartMessage

    return
  }

  try {#4
    Delete-Folder # has to include backing up first
  }
  catch {# rollback 3, 2 & 1
    Write-Error '#4 Fail'

    Revert-CreateFile
    Revert-FolderMove
    Undo-StartMessage

    return
  }

  try {#5
    Write-CompleteMessage
  }
  catch {# rollback 4, 3, 2 & 1
    Write-Error '#5 Fail'

    Revert-DeleteFile
    Revert-CreateFile
    Revert-FolderMove
    Undo-StartMessage

    return
  }

}
```

AND, this still only works if the script isn't aborted or the system crashes. In that case you have to make sure the result of each previous step is stored in a persistent way and that rerunning the script will resume it at the correct step.

(I won't provide that example)